# Need help finding specific folders

Tags: regex, powershell, get-childitem

I am trying to get a list of folders with `Get-ChildItem` and regex, but it's not working as expected. Below is the beginning of the code. The rest is omitted.

```
foreach ($directory in $directories)
{
    $VNextDirs = @(Get-ChildItem -recurse -path "$path\$directory\Filehandler" |
                 Where-Object {
                     ($_.Name -match "^v(\s\d)" -or
                     $_.Name -match "^v(\sn)" -and
                     ($_.PSIsContainer)
                 }) | select -expand FullName
```

This matches the below folders.

```
"V 10.0.0.0",
"V 9.0.0.0",
"Sample Text V 10.0.0.0"
```

However, I only want it to match the first and second ones (where it's V space any digits), not where there is any text preceding it (as in the 3rd entry). So it should not match "Sample Text V 10.0.0.0", but it should match "V 10.0.0.0" and "V 9.0.0.0".

My code is selecting all the folders I want, but it's also including that pesky folder where the "V space digit" is not on the beginning of the folder name.

How can I change this so that it only matches the folders I want?

**Note:** I also have it set to match "V space and the letter N" like this "V Next Build", but this is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Just FYI: it looks like you can merge the patterns into 1 `"^v(\s[\dn])"`. Please also try replacing `^` with `\A`.

Comment: What PowerShell version do you have? `Get-host`

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with the code you show. I just get the two folders returned from my sample.

Comment: I am using Powershell version 3.0, but on windows 7.

Comment: Thanks stribizhev! I used what you suggested to merge the two together and this worked.

Comment: Maybe unrelated, but you have a spurious opening parenthesis in your `Where-Object` filter.